# My WordPress site is taking too long to load on Android web-view. On a normal browser it loads under 2 seconds. How to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, performance, webview, lag

My WordPress site takes too long (43 secs) to load on Android web-view

I already have cdn and i optimised the site in every way I can. I also have wp rocket on top of cdn to improve site Speed. Someone please help me solve this.